# How to connect one local repository to more than one remote repository?

Tags: git

In my office, my computer has already init a local git repository which is also connect to a remote repository in github.

But recently my manager asked me to submit my codes to our own git server which only works in LAN. It means I have to work only in office but I don't want to do that.

So is there any way to let my local repository connect both in github and company server? Or can I use different branch to connect them.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: I'm not sure you could ask a more fundamental question about Git. This is the entire reason Git exists - as a **distributed** source code control system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up as many remotes as you like. When you clone git will set up origin for you by default but you can add others at any time. Use the command `git remote add <name> <url>`, e.g. `git remote add office git@git.office.com/myrepo.git`

To see all remotes you have, run the command `git remote -v`

More info is available [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)